# JMeter: Network Latency, CPU Usage and Memory

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing

How to setup PerfMon Metrics Collector properly, I have just installed JMeter Plugins and add PerfMon on my TestPlan.

Answer (score 0):

1. Network [Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) is something JMeter measures itself, you don't need to additionally collect it

   > **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.
2. In order to measure CPU and RAM usage

   - Download [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) and install it on the server which you would like to monitor
   - Launch ServerAgent (make sure that TCP and UDP inbound/outbound traffic is allowed on port `4444` in the firewall)
   - Add PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to your Test Plan
   - Configure it like:

     [image]
   - Run your test. Make sure it lasts longer than several seconds - you should see the CPU and Memory usage charts plotted.

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for comprehensive instructions on PerfMon installation, configuration and usage.